# How do I hardcode the result for one column based on another column's result

Tags: sql

I am new to sql and have browsed stack overflow and do not understand the trigger function, set function suggested to do this. I believed this could be done with case when statement.

I have the following result using the query also provided below. 
The result shows two different "Types" for the Symbol X with two different Weights. I would like to have the result show the sum of both the 1 type X and the 2 type X as 1 X.  So the result will show Type 1, Symbol X, Weight 2.95.

```
Type    Symbol  Price   Weight 
1   g       1.17
1   h       1.24
1   x       1
2   x       1.95
2   a       2.4
2   b       1.16
2   c       2.9
2   d       0.97
2   e       1.11
2   f       1.54

SELECT 'Type','Symbol','Price','Weight'
UNION
Select type,
symbol
,IFNULL(price,'')
,weight 
from lcv
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the logic behind wanting to do this for `x`, but not for `a` and `b`?

Comment: You are correct. I would want to do it for those as well. In my actual example, it only occurs with one symbol. I should have had the first to be 1g, and 1h to reflect more accurately the actual example.

Comment: In that case, google `SQL GROUP BY`

Comment: i have updated the table in the question to reflect more accurately.

Comment: when i do the group by the result shows as type 2 symbol x instead of type 1 symbol x.

Comment: Use the MIN() function on the `type` column.